# Find $\;\lim{\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}}\;$ where $f(x)$ is a solution to differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Find  $\;\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}}\;$ of the greatest value where f(x) is a solution to differential equation.
Choices :
$$ 1.\;\; y''+5y'-6=0, \;\;y(0)=-1,\;\;y'(0)=1$$
$$ 2. \;\;4y''-8y'+3y=0, \;\;y(0)=2,\;\;y'(0)=1$$
$$ 3.\;\; 4y''-4y'+y=0, \;\;y(0)=2,\;\;y'(0)=1$$
$$ 4.\;\; 2x^2y''+3xy'-y=0, \;\;x>0, \;\;y(1)=0,\;\;y(2)=1$$

---

I could find all solution to these DE and have the answer from them, 
 but it would be quite cumbersome.
Is there another way?

Comment: Why not divide by $y$? Seems like you would have a $\frac{y'}{y}$ term in each equation

Comment: 2 and 3 are linear homogeneous ODEs, with solutions of the form $y(x) = c_1 e^{\lambda_1 x} + c_2 e^{\lambda_2 x}$ where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are roots of the characteristic equation. If $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are real and $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2$, then you just need to check that the initial conditions don't force $c_2 = 0$ and then you know that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = c_2$ (the other cases are a bit more complicated but still easy to reason out).

Comment: @ConnorHarris  1 is also linear

Comment: @Isham but not homogeneous

Comment: nik, you would solve 4 with variation of parameters?

Comment: 4 is Euler Cauchy equation, so $y(x)=c_1x^{\lambda_1}+c_2x^{\lambda_2}$ and so...

Comment: @ConnorHarris Why isn't 1 homogeneous? It's been year 6 years since I've taken ODE, but it has =0 soooo?

Comment: @BCLC but there's a $-6$ on the other side

Comment: @Holo [4 can be solved with variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Euler_equation#Second_order_–_solving_through_trial_solution) ?

Comment: @ConnorHarris 2 and 3 have $y^1$ term. I seem to recall that's worse than a $y^0$ term. How are 2 and 3 homogeneous while 1 isn't? (looks up) oh ok [looks like you're right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equation_with_constant_coefficients). carry on.

Comment: @BCLC maybe, but change of variables is easier, why do you want variation of parameters?

Comment: @ConnorHarris  you mean $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \lambda_2?$$

Comment: @Holo Just wondering if it could be done.

Comment: @BCLC I never tried, it probably possible but I don't know how hard it will be

Comment: Thanks. I guess It could be simpler for the choices 2 and 3.

Comment: @Holo: yes, I meant $\lambda_2$. Thanks for catching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is easy to integrate

Last one is also easy to integrate

$$2x^2y''+3xy'-y=0$$
$$2x^2y''+4xy'-xy'-y=0$$
$$(2x^2y')'-(xy)'=0$$
$$2x^2y'-xy=K_1$$
Which is a first order diff equation
$$y'-\frac y {2x}=\frac {C_1}{x^2}$$
Use integrating factor $\mu (x)=x^{-1/2}$
$$(yx^{-1/2})'=\frac {C_1}{x^{5/2}}$$
After integrating, you finally get that :
$$\boxed {y(x)=K_1\sqrt x+ \frac {K_2} x}$$

Comment: I'm not sure how it leads to $\lim{(f'/f)}$.

Comment: it's a first order equation ....@nik

Comment: I see. You were  talking about how to find f. Thanks, It'd be faster than Cachy-Euler eqn way IF I could see it as you did...

Comment: Yeah thats what I meant it was at first sight a second order diff equation with variable coefficients but it reduces easily to a first orfer differential equation... Euler's method is great too